# What is the proper way of using ng-repeat to set attributes on an element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have the following div:

```
<div ng-repeat="player in playersScores" class="sb_lane">
                <div class='sb_animation drop'></div>
                <div lane="{{player.lane}}" class='dropbox' dropbucket>
                    <div  class='sb_lHeader'>
                        <div class="drop">Lane {{player.lane}}</div>
                        <div class="drop">{{player.player}}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sb_rScore drop">Run : {{cRun}} of {{tRun}}
                        <div>Run Score</div>
                        <div >{{player.rScore}}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sb_tScore drop">Game Score
                        <div > {{player.gScore}}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I am getting an error from using {{player.lane}} in the this line:

```
<div lane="{{player.lane}}" class='dropbox' dropbucket>
```

My question is this: What is the proper way of using ng-repeat to set attributes on an element?

Comment: can you show what `playerScores` looks like? is it an array or an object?

Comment: Is the lane attribute a custom directive you have defined in angular?

Comment: Careful about using custom jQuery attributes you might lose your angular licence xD.

Comment: Lane is not a custom directive.. in this case it is just an additional piece of data I need for drag and drop.

playersScore looks like: 

 [ { lane=1,  player="A",  gscore=0, rscore=0}]

Comment: This is not a custom JQuery attribute. It is a data attribute for another directive. I was hardcoding the html and am trying to move it into a proper angularjs methodology using ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
<div lane="player.lane" class='dropbox' dropbucket>
```

Comment: Tried that.. all I get is player.lane as text, not what is in player.lane coming from the ng-repeat.

Comment: i think `lane` is a directive

Comment: lane is not a directive. It is a data attribute used in a drag and drop directive I have. It is not a directive on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had a two way binding in the drag and drop directive that was set to lane. Once I removed that binding, everything worked as expected.

Thanks for the insight everyone..

Z